# Convertir el contenido de cada elemento un objeto de una API en un array con React y Split

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo una api con el objeto {"result": {"numero": 16330}} y el numero 16330 quiero convertirlo en un array con cada cada elemento separado usando split, el problema es que cuando uso split, el compilador tira error pero si hago un console.log con split me muestra los datos en pantalla como quiero que aparezcan

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import api from './api.jsx';

// Always Uppercase
export default function Results(){
    function prevDay(x){
        let prev = new Date();    
        prev.setDate(prev.getDate() + (x-(7+prev.getDay())) % 7); // obtener sabado pasado
        return prev.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace('T',' ') ;
    }

    const [responseApi, setResponseApi] = useState(null);
    const [date, setDate] = useState(prevDay(6));
    const [combination, setCombination] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      getResults(date);
      setCombination(responseApi.result.numero.split('')); //ERROR
    }, [ responseApi, date ])
    function getResults(date) {
    api.get(`localhost:8080/result/get_last_result?date=${date}`)
      .then(res => {
        setResponseApi(res.data.result.numero);
        //Al hacer console.log devuelve: 16880
        return res.data;
      });
  }

    return (<h1>results: {combination}</h1>);
}
```

este codigo deberia devolver: results: 1, 6, 3, 3, 0

Comment: Si compartes como te llega la data a la que le haces split seguramente recibiras mas ayuda.

Comment: https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61856298ad0eb745bd8a3f4c

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que en algún momento `responseApi.result.numero` te devuelve un tipo `number`, entonces tienes que convertir a `string`  primero.

```
(responseApi.result.numero+'').split('')
```